# Red object tracking in a video in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I have an assignment in which I need to track an object with a red color in a video, I think that everything works fine except when I want to preview the result. It doesn't show any results when executing and I need to stop the program in the middle of it to get a figure of a random frame proccessed correctly.
Can you help me please ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is the code is looping faster than it can update the figure. To fix this you should add a `drawnow` in your loop; this will force the figures to update immediately.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked perfectly.